# Load a list of localized strings at once in IOS

Tags: ios

I want to show a table with the list of strings which are localized.

The straightforward method would be:

a) Point data source to my ViewController

b) Define an array

c) Allocate the array in my ViewController and init (arrayWithObjects) it with the strings from localized resources (NSLocalizedString)

d) Use this array in UITableViewDataSource delegated methods

Mainly my concern is item b). The construction looks quite heavy and I wonder whether I can somehow specify and load whole list of localized string at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to have an array that contains **all** the keys defined in your `Localizable.strings` file?

That's pretty easy actually, as `.strings` files are in a format that correspond the the Old-ASCII-Style for the plist format containing a dictionary (the enclosing curly braces that normally need to be present in this Old-ASCII-Style plist format to enclose a dictionary being silently ignored).

So you can simply load the content of your `Localizable.strings` file into a `NSDictionary` and you are good to go!

```
NSString* stringsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings"];
NSDictionary* locStringsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:stringsPath];
NSLog(@"locStringsDict = %@", locStringsDict);
NSArray* localizedStrings = locStringsDict.allValues;
NSLog(@"All localized strings in current language = %@", localizedStrings);
```

---

Of course if you only want some of the localized strings, you could:

- Either put the strings you want in a separate ".strings" file (a.k.a. different Strings table)
- Or make an NSArray of all the keys corresponding to the strings you need, and then loop thru them to build your NSArray of localized string for these keys, calling `NSLocalizedString` on each key entry

---

*[EDIT]*

Note that it seems that **`strings` files are compiled into binary plists** before being embedded in the final application (just tested it on a sample project). Thus once your application is running, the `Localizable.strings` file **is a binary plist** (namely `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:stringsPath encoding:0 error:nil]` will **not** return the original content of your `Localizable.strings` file but some binary data interpreted as some junk string, and the original file is not accessible anymore)

So if you want to keep the order of the keys, the only other option is to parse the original `strings` file before compilation, and not at runtime. The best choice for that is probably IMHO to convert the `strings` file into an XML Plist using `plutil -convert xml1 Localizable.strings -o -` and extract the keys from there, for example using some simple XSLT stylesheet. The stylesheet could even directly turn the extracted keys into some new XML plist that will represent an NSArray of those keys, in the expected order, so you can load this plist into an NSArray by code and use them at runtime.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know about dictionaryWithContentsOfFile. However, this approach has one problem. "allValues" will have undefined order. And I need the same order as file has.

Comment: @VictorRonin Does your file have any type of order or is it just arbitrary?

Comment: I hoped that I can show strings in the same order as they are presented in the file. Generally I open for any file format which will allow me both do localization and specify order.

Comment: Then that would be much more difficult, as you will thus need to _parse_ the Localizable.strings file, taking into account the possible comments, and also the case when a string value is written accross multiple lines! (see example in my edited answer)

Comment: One other way though: would you consider filling this array at compile time and not at runtime? Converting your `Localizable.strings` file into the XML Plist format using the `plutil -convert xml1` command line would produce an XML plist that will be easier to parse by code then (or thru an XSLT stylesheet that will generate the Objective-C code directly, for what it's worth, or whatever other method), allowing you to keep the order of the keys at that point.

Comment: Actually it seems after a brief test that `Localizable.strings` files are converted to binary plists at compile time (which confirms that they are in fact PLIST files ;)). So this means that at runtime your original `Localizable.strings` file is no longer available e.g. for parsing the file and finding the order of the keys you expect. Your best move here is to parse this Localizable.strings file before compilation (easiest way being to convert it to XML plist then apply some XSLT) and embeded the result (namely an array of the keys, ordered) in your final bundle.

Comment: Just saw that there is a build setting called `STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCDING`, that defaults to binary, but you can still change it to defaults to UTF16 for example, so that the embedded `Localizable.strings` file in your bundle will normally remain in a ASCII file format so you can parse its text. But I'm not sure that you can count on the fact that the compiled strings file will keep the order of the keys anyway… and it will still be hard to  parse an ASCII text file as opposed to an XML file.